# What is the opposite of penance?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, antonyms

I think it must be a single word from something like "willful insistence on wrongdoing." What is that word? A lot of websites say "happiness" which seems obviously incorrect.

Comment: *Delicious iniquity*?

Comment: Instead of punishing ones self for wrongdoings, one punishes others? Or does one celebrate ones wrongdoings? Or does one punish themselves for doing good deeds? Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *profligacy*? *Oxford* defines *[profligate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/profligate#profligate)* as

> Licentious; dissolute:
>   *he succumbed to drink and a profligate lifestyle*

As similarly, the referenced *licentiousness* and *dissolution*.

The simple antonym is *[unrepentant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unrepentant)*

> Showing no regret for one’s wrongdoings:
>   *he was unrepentant and said that his comments were completely accurate*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*